# Extracting coordinates from USB GPS sensor with python

Tags: python, gps, port, sensors

I have a u-blox usb gps-sensor I wish to use to obtain coordinates. I should be able to access the device under a COM port through the u-center2 software. However, the device is listed under "sensors" in my device manager. When I manually uninstall the driver, the device gets listed as COM port for a short moment, before the driver reinstalls itself and the device is again listed as sensor.

My thought was to, instead of using the u-center2 software, accessing the coordinates directly through python using the automatically generated status of the device (sensor and not COM port). I found code from an earlier post and tried to change it to my purposes:

```
import time, serial

port ='Port_#0003.Hub_#0003' #name of the port I want to access

ser = serial.Serial(port) #here is an error, I get: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

ser.baudrate = 9600

line = ser.readline()

line2 = line.decode('latin-1')

print(line2.find("$GPGGA") != -1) #true when Lat & Long is available

print(line)
```

I am an absolute beginner with python. I am confident that I installed the components "time" and "serial", and that I gave python permission to access the ports. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use the `serial` module to list the available ports. You could use this to find out if the problem is that you are using the wrong `port` name.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1, unfortunately the device is listed as sensor and I was not able to permanently transfer it to a com (serial) port.